# sidebar and content slide according to the sidebar link in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, sidebar

I just want to get a page just like in this link in wordpress. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#top .When we click the links in the sidebar the content slides down to their respective content. Help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: please explain your question.

Comment: @Riteshdjoshi as u see the link there are links in the right sidebar of the page and when we click in that link the related contents are shown in sliding manner now i want the same feature in my wordpress sites one page. That is what i am trying to explain.

Comment: are you able to send me the wordpress link.

Comment: @Riteshdjoshi, Sorry i am doing it in local not yet uploaded in server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this menu link like href="#idname" and add the id in content like
```

Add this code in content section

```
<div id="test">
// Paste everything here
</div>
```

add this code in sidebar

```
<a href="#test">Test</a>
```

Wordpress menu provide add href section.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

Add below line above the content or div in html

```
<h1 id="code">Title goes here</h1>
```

Then, in sidebar link, add `#code` after url